# How to disable all past dates as well as today from bootstarp datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker.

I have used the code to disable sunday, saturday and all earlier dates, but I need to disable today also. How can I do this ?

Here is my code

```
function disableWeekends($this) {
        var $days = $this.find('.datepicker-days tr').each(function() {
            var $days = $(this).find('.day');
            // disable Sunday
            $days.eq(0).addClass('disabled').click(false);
            // disable Saturday
            $days.eq(6).addClass('disabled').click(false);
        });
    }

// create the date picker
        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);



$('#demo_date').datepicker({
            onRender: function(date) {
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
            $('.help-tip').popover('hide');                
        });

        // get instance of the jQuery object created by
        // datepicker
        var datepicker = $('#demo_date').data('datepicker');

        if(datepicker) {
            // disable weekends in the pre-rendered version
            disableWeekends(datepicker.picker);

            // disable weekends whenever the month changes
            var _fill = datepicker.fill;
            datepicker.fill = function () {
                _fill.call(this);
                disableWeekends(this.picker);
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `startDate` and `daysOfWeekDisabled` options to get the required result.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '+1d',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<input class="datepicker" type="text">
```

**Bootstrap 2.2.2:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '+1d',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<input class="datepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: i am using bootstarp 2.2 version and datepicker as Version 2.0

Comment: So it should work with Bootstrap 2.0.4+ (see: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/#requirements).

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
```

Replace `<` with `<=`.

Comment: I tried this but it not working when i clik text box to open datepicker. when i select any date then its disabling today.

Comment: Using Chrome developer tools or Firebug or another javascript console, what does `now.valueOf()` return?

Comment: its giving 1418754600000

Comment: Okay, it might be an issue with the time part of that timestamp, try replacing `now.valueOf()` with `ceil(now.valueOf()/86400000)*84600000-1`